# if statement not executing correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter

This might seem simple but is not correctly working. The if statement looks correct. I am basically saying that if there is data in the table show everything in brackets otherwise do not show at all.
In psuedo code I am doing this:

```
if (query > = 1) {

//show foreach loop and clear form button

} else {

//do not show anything

}
```

In real markup I have tried this:

```
 <?php if($user_promos >= 1) { ?>

             <?php
            if($user_promos){
                //print_r($user_promos);
            ?>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3>Add Event To Location</h3>
                <div class="row">

                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="row">

                    <div id="myselect2" class="col-md-12">
                        <p></p>

                      <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-3">
                      <?php 
                        //$user_events = '';
                        //print_r($user_events);
                        $ar=array();
                        foreach($user_events as $events) {
                            $ar[$events['id']] = $events['title'];
                            }
                      //endforeach;
                        ?>

                        <?php
                        $attributes = '';
                         //$attributes='';
                         echo form_dropdown('myselect', $ar, '',$attributes);    

                        ?> 

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              </div>
              <?php    
              }
              ?>
              <button id="grab1" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
                      <hr/>
            </div>
             <?php    
              }
              ?>
```

Update:

Variable user_promos is the variable set to the query. The query in the dropdown_add_promos method is returned as an array.

```
$data['user_promos'] = $this->model_location->dropdown_add_promos($fkUserId);
```

Comment: Is $user_promos is an array or an integer ?

Comment: @Khushboo Please see update at the bottom of my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `count()` since its an `array` it will give you count of number of items in array

```
if(count($user_promos) >= 1)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you are setting $data['user_promos'] but you are checking on $user_promos... that may be the issue.

do you get anything from that

```
<?php
if($user_promos){
//print_r($user_promos);
?>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($data['user_promos']))
{
  // check
  if(count($data['user_promos']) > 0) 
  {
     //do something
  }
  else{
     // don't do anything
  }
}
else
{
// error message
}
```

**You should try above condition.**

Inner condition is used only if you want to count the data otherwise outer condition is enough to check data is coming or not.